# virtual isomorphism of groups is an equivalence relation

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I am reading the book: Geometric Group Theory by
Cornelia Druţu and Michael Kapovich With an Appendix by Bogdan Nica. [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/ggt.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/EPR/ggt.pdf). On page 125 we have:

*Def: We say that two groups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are virtually isomorphic (abbreviated as VI) if there exist finite-index subgroups $H_{i} \subset G_{i}$ and finite normal subgroups $F_{i}\triangleleft H_{i}$, i = 1, 2, so that the quotients $H_{1}/F_{1}$ and $H_{2}/F_{2}$ are isomorphic.

The authors proved, on page 125 Proposition 5.15, that the virtual isomorphism relation is an equivalence relation between groups.

The proof goes as follows:

- The normal closure of the union of two finite normal subgroups is a finite subgroup. Suppose now that $G_{1}$ is VI to $G_{2}$ and $G_{2}$ is VI to $G_{3}$.  Then we have
  $F_{i} \triangleleft H_{i} < G_{i}$, $|G_{i} :H_{i}|<\infty$, $|F_{i}|<\infty$, $i=1,2,3$, and
  $F_{2}’\triangleleft H_{2}’< G_{2}$, $|G_{2} : H_{2}’| < \infty$, $| F_{2}’ | < \infty$, so that
  $H_{1}/F_{1}\cong H_{2}/F_{2}$ and $H_{2}’/F_{2}’\cong H_{3}/F_{3}$.
  Now $H_{2}’’=H_{2}\cap H_{2}‘$ has finite index in $G_{2}$.  Let $K_{2}$ be the normal closure in $H_{2}’’$ of the union of the finite subgroups $H_{2}’’\cap F_{2}$ and $H_{2}’’\cap F_{2}’$.
  **From** now on things become unclear to me.

  We have quotient maps:
  $f_{i}:H_{2}’’\rightarrow C_{i}=f_{i}(H_{2}’’)\leq H_{i}/F_{i}$, $i=1,3$, with finite kernels and cokernels.  (I am not sure how these maps are defined.) The subgroups $E_{i} \mathrel{:=} f_{i}(K_{2})$ are finite and normal in $C_{i}$, $i = 1,3$.  (This is obvious to me.) We let $H_{i}’,F_{i}’ \subset H_{i}$ denote the preimages of $C_{i}$ and $E_{i}$ under the quotient maps $H_{i} \rightarrow H_{i}/F_{i}$, $i = 1,3$. Then $|F_{2}’| < \infty$, $|G_{i} : H_{i}’| < \infty$, $i = 1,3$.
  Lastly (this is completely unclear to me),
  $H_{i}’/F_{i}’\cong C_{i}/E_{i}\cong H_{2}’’/K_{2}$, $i=1,3$.

My attempt to convince myself:
Consider the isomorphisms
$g_{1}:H_{2}/F_{2}\rightarrow H_{1}/F_{1}$ and $g_{3}:H_{2}’/F_{2}’\rightarrow H_{3}/F_{3}$. Then $g_{1}$ induces a surjective homomorphism $f_{1}:H_{2}\rightarrow H_{1}/F_{1}$ given by $f_{1}(x)=g_{1}(xF_{2})$; similarly $g_{2}$ induces a surjective homomorphism $f_{3}:H_{2}’\rightarrow H_{3}/F_{3}$ given by $f_{3}(x)=g_{3}(xF_{2}’)$. Restricting to $H_{2}’’$, we obtain the quotient maps:
$f_{i}:H_{2}’’\rightarrow C_{i}=f_{i}(H_{2}’’)\leq H_{i}/F_{i}$, $i=1,3$. However, I cannot justify the isomorphisms
$H_{i}’/F_{i}’\cong C_{i}/E_{i}\cong H_{2}’’/K_{2}$, $i=1,3$.

Comment: That TeX was a bit of an adventure.  I have edited to fix, I believe without changing any semantics.  I was a little unclear if something was missing in the definition of $K_2$, which you say is the normal closure of two subgroups.  I also deleted “Thank you!”, which the usual SO norms omit.

Comment: I edited the definition of $K_{2}$.

Comment: @MarkSapir oh yes, the same subgroups may not be witnessing the two isomorphisms... of course

Comment: This book should not call this "virtual isomorphism". It doesn't respect a quite universal use of "virtual" (which does not include modding out finite kernels). I hope this confusing terminology will not be extensively used.

Comment: @YCor Some authors call this weak commensurability.

Comment: Basically, the nontrivial point in these things is the following lemma: let $H\le G$ have finite index, and let $K$ be a finite normal subgroup of $H$. Then $K$ is contained in a finite normal subgroup $K'$ of $G$. The proof uses the following **fact**: in an FC-group, the torsion forms a locally finite subgroup. Once this is known, $K$ is contained in the FC-center of $H$, which is contained in the FC-center of $G$, and hence so do the finitely many conjugates of $K$ in $G$. By the fact, these generate a finite subgroup $K'$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here is a proof (I just fixed it). Let $F_i\triangleleft H_i<_{f.i.} G_i$, $i=1,2$, $F'_i\triangleleft H_i'<_{f.i.} G_i, i=2,3$ and $f\colon H_1\to  H_2/F_2, g\colon H_2' \to H_3'/F_3'$ be surjective homomorphisms with kernels $F_1, F_2'$.  Let 
   $H=H_2\cap H_2' <_{f.i} G_2$.  Then $H/(H\cap F_2')\cong HF_2'/F_2'<_{f.i.} H_2'/F_2'<_{f.i.} H_3'/F_3'$.

Let $P$ be $f^{-1}((H\cap F_2')/(H\cap F_2'\cap F_2)$.  Then $P$ is normal in $U=f^{-1}(H/F_2)$ which is of f.i. in $G_1$. Therefore $U/P\cong H/(H\cap F_2'\cap F_2)$ which is of f.i. in $H_3'/F_3'$ (see above), the proof is complete. The proof uses two standard isomorphism theorems in group theory (the second and the third, I think).

This is not the only proof available. As I was
 told by M. Kapovich, it is Proposition 5.15 in  the book by Drutu and Kapovich. "For the proof, we first prove Lemma 5.16 and then finish the proof of the proposition."

Comment: Plain, simple and beautiful! Thank you Prof. Mark Sapir!

Comment: I am writing down the proof and I am wondering why we would  have $HF_2/F_2<_{f.i.}H_3'/F_3'$?

Comment: That is true if $HF_2'/F_2'$ is a subgroup of $H_2/F_2.$

Comment: yes, it needs a longer explanation. Thank you!

Comment: I will fix it tonight.

Comment: @HussainRashed: The proof is fixed.

Comment: Thank you, prof. Mark Sapir! I know that my question is proved in Proposition 5.15 in the book by Drutu and Kapovich. But, I didn't understand the last step of their proof as I stated in the question. However, your proof is by far easier to follow. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, but I keep making the same mistake. The proof is really simple. Take $H$ to be intersection of $H_2 \cap H_2'$. Take its image in $H_2/F_2$ and then preimage under $f$. That is the new $H_1$. Then take its image under $ g$ and preimage under $H_3' \to H_3'/F_3'$. That is the new $H_3$. Finding the f'inite normal sungroups is then obvious.

Comment: By the way, the normal closure of the union of two normal subgroups A and B is their product AB (that implies Lemma 5.16). And while we are at it, there are more trivial group theory facts. For example, for every subgroup $H$ and normal subgroup $A$, $AH=HA$.